# Effort.Exceptions.EffortException : Database has not been initialized - after non commited update?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, effort

### Why does this exception occur?  Is this a bug?

I'm using Effort, the EF testing library to create an in memory instance of my database and run into this interesting scenario:

1. Open `DbContext1`
2. Add item to `Table` (do not save)
3. Close `DbContext1`
4. Open `DbContext2`
5. Count items in `Table`

`Effort.Exceptions.EffortException : Database has not been initialized.`

However, if I perform a count (step 5) also in `DbContext1` then the Count in `DbContext2` doesn't fail?

**Full Code**:

```
public void TestEF()
{
   var factory = new InMemoryMyApplicationDbContextFactory();

   using (var db = factory.CreateDbContext())
   {
      //uncomment this line to prevent exception - why????
      //db.Orders.Count();

      db.Orders.Add(new Order{ Id = Guid.NewGuid() }); 

      // intentionally do not call db.SaveChanges()
   }

   using (var db = factory.CreateDbContext())
   {
      // throws an exception if no read was performed above
      db.Orders.Count();
   }    
}
```

**Full Exception:**

```
Effort.Exceptions.EffortException : Database has not been initialized.

If using CodeFirst try to add the following line:
   context.Database.CreateIfNotExists()
 at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)
 at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlan.Execute[TResultType](ObjectContext context, ObjectParameterCollection parameterValues)
 at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)
 at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass7.<GetResults>b__5()
 at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
 at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator>b__0()
 at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext()
 at System.Linq.Enumerable.Single[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
```

Comment: Also filed Issue on Effort project site: https://github.com/tamasflamich/effort/issues/79

Answer (score 2):

I took the advice mentioned in the exception message and added the following line to my test within the `using` statement

```
    db.Database.CreateIfNotExists();
```

and that worked for me.

Comment: Which using statement, the first or the 2nd?

Comment: The problem only occurs with two `using` statements.  If you have only one, then the exception does not occur

Comment: well, it did occur to me... I don't know why you downvoted this but that's up to you...